# Why is huffman encoded text bigger than actual text?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

I am trying to understand how Huffman coding works and it is supposed to compress data to take less memory than actual text but when I encode for example

```
"Text to be encoded"
```

which has **18** characters the result I get is

```
"100100110100101110101011111000001110011011110010101100011"
```

Am I supposed to divide those result bits by `8` since character has `8` bits?

Comment: Actual result is `10010011 01001011 10101011 11100000 11100110 11110010 10110001 00000001` - **8** ASCII characters (technically, you should not *divide* by 8, but *group* by 8 bit chunks). More accurate is `"Text to be encoded" == 18 * 8 = 144 bits` before and `57` bits after the compression

Comment: "Text to be encoded" is a string. Each character in the uncompressed string is represented by an 8-bit ASCII character making the total uncompressed string 18*8=144 bits. The Huffman code is 57 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compare the *same* units (*bits* as in the after the compession or *characters* as in the text before), e.g.

```
before: "Text to be encoded" == 18 * 8 bits = 144 bits
                             == 18 * 7 bits = 126 bits (in case of 7-bit characters)
after:  100100110100101110101011111000001110011011110010101100011 = 57 bits
```

so you have **144** (or **126**) bits before and **57** bits after the compression. Or

```
before: "Text to be encoded" == 18 characters
after:   10010011 
         01001011
         10101011
         11100000
         11100110
         11110010
         10110001
         00000001 /* the last chunk is padded */ == 8 characters
```

so you have **18** ascii characters before and only **8** one byte characters after the compression. If characters are supposed to be `7-bit` (`0..127` range Ascii table) we have **9** characters after the compression:

```
after:  1001001 'I'
        1010010 'R'
        1110101 'u'
        0111110 '>'
        0000111 '\0x07'
        0011011 '\0x1B'
        1100101 'e'
        0110001 'l'
        0000001 '\0x01'
```

Comment: "only 8 ascii characters after"  --> More like 8 _bytes_ as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only defined for values 0-127.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.